# regex to get "words" delimited by space(s)?

Tags: ios, regex, swift, nsregularexpression

What would the regex be (to be used in IOS, "NSRegularExpression") to get the "words" from a string delimited by a space(s), i.e. could be " ", or "  ", or "   " etc as the delimited.

So therefore:

```
"26:43:33 S     153:02:51   E"
```

Would give:

```
1-"26:43:33"
2-"S"
3-"153:02:51"
4-"E"
```

Comment: Why use a regex? Just split the string on spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So therefore:
>
> ```
> "26:43:33 S     153:02:51   E"
> ```
>
> Would give:
>
> ```
> 1-"26:43:33"
> 2-"S"
> 3-"153:02:51"
> 4-"E"
> ```

So if you're going to use a regex for this, you want to look for all contiguous stretches of not-space. Like this:

```
let s = "26:43:33 S     153:02:51   E" as NSString
let pattern = "[^ ]+"
let reg = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let matches = reg.matchesInString(s as String, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, s.length))
let result = matches.map {s.substringWithRange($0.range)}
// result is: ["26:43:33", "S", "153:02:51", "E"]
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to regex, I would suggest using the `split` method on your string.

```
let string = "26:43:33 S     153:02:51   E"
let words = string.characters.split { $0 == " " }.map { String($0) }
```

Because calling `split` on the characters property will return an array of `Character` types, we need to use the `map` method to convert them back to strings. `map` will perform a closure on each element of a collection. In this case we just use it to cast each element to a `String`

Comment: I agree completely. The use case in the OP's particular question seems an unnecessary use of regex. My answer was intended merely to show how you _would_ do it _if_ you were using regex; in a more complex case, I suppose it might be useful.

Comment: Does multiple spaces not impact this however?

Comment: No they won't have an impact.